# Access VBA: Query returns no rows

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, dao, ms-access-2010

I've written some VBA:

```
For x = LBound(resProdID) To UBound(resProdID)
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qry_findID_vba").SQL = "" & _
    "SELECT tbl_products.ProdID " & _
    "FROM tbl_products " & _
    "WHERE (tbl_products.Size = " & resSize(x) & " " & _
    "AND tbl_products.SupplID = '" & Forms.frm_suppliers.SupplID & "')"

    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Set dbs = CurrentDb()
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("qry_findID_vba")

    MsgBox rst.RecordCount

    If rst.RecordCount <> 0 Then
        rst.MoveLast
        rst.MoveFirst

        newProdID(x) = rst.Fields(0).Value
        MsgBox "This never fires"
     End If

    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    dbs.Close
    Set dbs = Nothing
Next x
```

What happens when I run it, is that a box pops up saying 0. I click Ok, and it repeats one more time. This is because I have two items in my resProdID-array.

However, if I open the query "qry_findID_vba" normally, it shows one row, like I expected.

Why doesn't VBA return this row? Have I done anything wrong?

Comment: Have you verified that the values in the resSize array and in Forms.frm_suppliers.SupplID are, in fact, consistent with the values in the table you're searching?

Comment: What is your SQL? You should add a debug.print or a msgbox with that displays the SQL. Does that SQL return a row? If it doesn't, which is likely, then that's the problem.

Comment: DAO's pretty dated. Can I suggest switching to ADO instead?

Comment: @DavidW Yes, they are both integers. As you see, I modify an actual query, and if I open that after I've run the Sub, it shows one row. So I know it's there, VBA just doesn't find it. That's the strange thing, and I don't know why..

Comment: @DanielCook Yes, I outputted the SQL as the default value of a InputBox. Then I tried running the SQL in a query object, and it worked as expected. If you look at the comment above, I've verified that the object "qry_findID_vba" is inded working..

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I'm going to try it and see if it changes anything.

Comment: Also - you are setting 'qry_findID_vba', but opening 'qry_frm_findID_vba'. Are these supposed to be the same name?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Sorry, they are the same. I just had to change the name of the query to strip down any unnececcary long names.. I've walked through names time after time. I also tried inserting the SQL directly into the OpenRecordset without luck..

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I should've done this earlier. The code above runs when you click a button. I made a new blank form, added a button on it, and copied exactly the code that doesn't work. And, it magically works.

Comment: The question is just, why does the same code work in one form, but not in the other one?

Comment: Two hours ago, about the same thing happened. I opened a report that has always worked, and it didn't work. It throwed an error that had no message. Then I deleted the report, and copied it in again from a backup. The two versions of the report was exactly the same... I don't see why these mystical things has to happen! I've seen more people report this on the web. I hate bugs..

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Do you have any idea as to what I can do?

Comment: If SupplID is an integer in the database, take off the quotes in the query, eg "AND tbl_products.SupplID = " & Forms.frm_suppliers.SupplID & ")"

Comment: @DaveidW SupplID is a String/VarChar. Size is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this code messagebox the correct count? Can you use it instead?
(Note, I haven't actually run it, so watch out for slight syntax errors.)

```
For x = LBound(resProdID) To UBound(resProdID) 
    Dim sql as String
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset 
    sql = "Select tbl_products.ProdID FROM tbl_products " & _
          "WHERE (tbl_products.Size = " & resSize(x) & " " & _
          "AND tbl_products.SupplID = '" & Forms.frm_suppliers.SupplID & "')" 
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(sql)
    if not rst.eof then 
        MsgBox rst.fields("ProdID")    
    else
        Msgbox "None found!"
    end if
    rst.Close 
    Set rst = Nothing 
Next x
```

Also, try copying everything to a new form, and compacting and repairing the database ...

Comment: If this approach of dumping the QueryDef approach altogether isn't suitable, let me know, and I'll just delete this answer.

Comment: Fixed up to MsgBox field instead of count.

Comment: I've tried using just the SQL instead of using the QueryDef approach. Same problem..

Comment: Is SupplID a text or a number?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17403/discussion-between-lynn-crumbling-and-friend-of-kim)

Comment: For posterity, copying everything to a new form, and compacting and repairing the database was what ended up resolving this.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you really should use QueryDef parameters. They provide a number of benefits:

- A safety net against malformed input and SQL injection.
- You don't need to redefine the query SQL text every time a parameter value changes.
- They make your VBA independent of the query text. This is a simple query, but more complex ones benefit if you don't have to change your VBA code just to change the SQL.
- They provide type safety - you can use typed variables in VBA and be sure that the query cannot fail with data type errors.
- They can be re-used - parameterized queries can be bound to forms, or executed directly, for example.
- Last but not least, it looks much nicer and clearer when used in VBA.

Your situation is exactly what parameterized QueryDefs are for.

Change the query text of `qry_findID_vba` in Access to:

```
PARAMETERS [ProductSize] Text (255), [SupplID] Number;
SELECT ProdID
FROM tbl_products
WHERE [tbl_products].[Size] = [ProductSize] AND [tbl_products].[SupplID] = [SupplID];
```

Replace the parameter data types according to your actual data types in the table.

Next, when you're in a loop, don't re-define fixed variables again and again. `dbs` and `rst` don't need to be defined inside the loop at all.

Last point, the `RecordCount` property does not work the way you think. [Quote from the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821452.aspx), emphasis mine:

> Use the `RecordCount` property to find out how many records in a
>   Recordset or TableDef object have been accessed. **The RecordCount
>   property doesn't indicate how many records are contained in a**
>   dynaset–, snapshot–, or forward–only–type **Recordset object until all
>   records have been accessed.**
>   [...]
>   To force the last record to be accessed, use the `MoveLast` method on the Recordset object.

Instead of calling `MoveLast`, you can also check the `.EOF` property. If it is false, at least one record is available.

For one-off query results like this one, I would recommend using the snapshot type Recordset. You can define [which type you want](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb225803%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to use when you call `OpenRecordset` on the QueryDef.

Now:

```
Dim qry_findID_vba As DAO.QueryDef 
Set qry_findID_vba = CurrentDb().QueryDefs("qry_findID_vba")

qry_findID_vba.Parameters("SupplID") = Forms.frm_suppliers.SupplID

For x = LBound(resProdID) To UBound(resProdID)
    qry_findID_vba.Parameters("ProductSize") = resSize(x)

    With qry_findID_vba.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)
        If Not .EOF Then 
            newProdID(x) = .Fields("ProdID").Value 
        End If
    End With
Next x
```

Note that I use `With` to save maintaining a helper `rst` variable.